# React native bugsnag

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement bugsnag in my project. I am getting an error that "You must provide a Bugsnag Api Key".

I have created a file named as CrashReporter.js

```
import { Client, Configuration } from "bugsnag-react-native";
const configuration = new Configuration();
const bugsnag = new Client(configuration);
class CrashReporter {
 attach() {
  configuration.appVersion = "1.4.5";
  configuration.apiKey = "0096f**acb8**c76e**ecf6e**a2";
 }

  setCurrentUser(userName, userID, userEmail) {
  bugsnag.setUser(userID, userName, userEmail);
  }

  notify(error) {
  bugsnag.notify(new Error(error));
  }
 }

 export default new CrashReporter();
```

index.js

```
 import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
 import App from "./App.js";
 import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

 import CrashReporter from "./src/services/CrashReporter";
 CrashReporter.attach();

 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Now, I am importing the CrashReporter file into different pages in my project using

```
 import CrashReporter from "../../services/CrashReporter";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change CrashReporter.js as follows to add `bugsnag` as an instance variable and then all should be fine.

```
import { Client, Configuration } from "bugsnag-react-native";
class CrashReporter {
 attach() {
const configuration = new Configuration();

  configuration.appVersion = "1.4.5";
  configuration.apiKey = "0096f**acb8**c76e**ecf6e**a2";
this.bugsnag = new Client(configuration);

 }

  setCurrentUser(userName, userID, userEmail) {
  this.bugsnag.setUser(userID, userName, userEmail);
  }

  notify(error) {
  this.bugsnag.notify(new Error(error));
  }
 }

 export default new CrashReporter();
```